# Call js function only once in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created js function and now i want that js function to call itself only once, My code is

```
function view(str){

   $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: '<?php echo base_url()?>index.php/main/'+str+'/',
      success: function(output_string){
         //i want to call function from here only once like view(str);
      }
   });
}
```

.
How can i do that ? Thanks in advance, Currently it is showing me infinte loop.

Comment: i am calling that function on anchor tag click like<a onclick="view('myfucntion')" href="#">

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a flag variable

```
var myflag = false;
function view(str) {
    $.ajax({
                type : "POST",
                url : '<?php echo base_url()?>index.php/main/' + str + '/',

                success : function(output_string) {
                    if (!myflag) {
                        view(str);
                    }
                    myflag = true;
                }
            });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a parameter to the function that keeps track of the count:

```
function view(str, count) {
  if (count > 0) {
    return;
  }

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '<?php echo base_url()?>index.php/main/'+str+'/',

    success: function(output_string) {
      view(count + 1);
      // i want to call function from here only once like view(str);
    }
  });
}
```

Then you would initially call `view` like this:

```
view(str, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a bool as a parameter on whether the function should call itself again:

```
function view(str, shouldCallSelf){

   $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: '<?php echo base_url()?>index.php/main/'+str+'/',
      success: function(output_string){
         if (shouldCallSelf)
             view(output_string, false)
      }
   });
}
```

You should call it with true the first time. It will then call itself with false the second time, will not execute again.

Answer (score 1):

you are looking for jquery `one`.
http://api.jquery.com/one/

fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/XKYeg/6/

```
<a href='#' id='lnk'>test</a>

$('#lnk').one('click', function view(str) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '<?php echo base_url()?>index.php/main/' + str + '/',

        success: function (output_string) {
            i want to call

            function from here only once like view(str);
        }
    });
});
```